# Can I use two RCO Add-A-Zones to control 3 zones (1 zone is split)?

Tags: watering, landscaping, irrigation

I have four trees that don't have irrigation right now.  I'm planning to add a zone using the RCO Add-a-Zone, restricted to watering them via Root Watering System. The problem, though, is I have a privacy fence and a 3-foot wide rock border that would intersect the trench between 2 of the 4 trees.

My controller has 11/12 zones used; this would be the 12th.

Is it possible to use the RCO(s) so that I don't need to trench through the fence and border?

- Zone 12a piggybacks off Zone 5
- Zone 12b piggybacks off Zone 3

The RCO requires a splitter between the host and guest zone at the controller. Can I run a pair of guest zone wires for Zone 12 to both Zones 3 and 5?